# How to identify and store center locations of dots in grid?

Tags: python, arrays, grid, tuples, coordinates

Ok for this I am somewhat looking for suggestions on what the next step should be and how to implement the one I am currently on.

First here is the context:
I am working on a project that involves finding the center of circles that have been put in a grid. The original image was 1260x683px and had 27x15 dots in a grid inside the image. The image is stored as a text file. In the text file a 0 represents a pixel that is not part of any dot, and a 1 represents a pixel that is part of a dot.

I want to figure out a way to identify the center coordinate of each dot. Below I made a few diagrams to show what I want to do.

- Fig 1. shows what the array looks like before any manipulation.
- Fig 2. shows how I want to identify all the non zero elements.
- Fig 3. Shows that I want to then narrow the identified elements to just the middle element of reach row and the middle column.
- Finally Fig 4. Shows the desired end goal to identify the center of each dot. From there once the center is identified. I want to be able to store its position as a tuple in a 27x15 array that will be used later to identify the center points.

Its worth noting that if there is a row with an even number of 1s I want to identify the right one of the two center values (Fig 0a.) and for the columns if there is an even number of 1s I want to identify the bottom one as the center (Fig 0b.)

Fig 0a.
00011**1**1000
..........^.......

Fig 0b.
0
0
0
1
1
**1** <--
1
0
0
0

Fig 1.
00011111100000000111111000...
00111111110000001111111100...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
00111111110000001111111100...
00011111100000000111111000...

Fig 2.
000**111111**00000000**111111**000...
00**1111111**1000000**11111111**00...
0**1111111111**0000**1111111111**0...
0**1111111111**0000**1111111111**0...
0**1111111111**0000**1111111111**0...
0**1111111111**0000**1111111111**0...
0**1111111111**0000**1111111111**0...
0**1111111111**0000**1111111111**0...
00**11111111**000000**11111111**00...
000**111111**00000000**111111**000...

Fig 3.
000111**1**1100000000111**1**11000...
001111**1**1110000001111**1**11100...
011111**1**1111000011111**1**11110...
011111**1**1111000011111**1**11110...
011111**1**1111000011111**1**11110...
0**11111*1*1111**0000**11111*1*1111**0...
011111**1**1111000011111**1**11110...
011111**1**1111000011111**1**11110...
001111**1**1110000001111**1**11100...
000111**1**1100000000111**1**11000...

Fig 4.
00011111100000000111111000...
00111111110000001111111100...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
011111**1**1111000011111**1**11110...
01111111111000011111111110...
01111111111000011111111110...
00111111110000001111111100...
00011111100000000111111000...

Overall the tldr is that I need to find a way to determine the centers of each dot in a 27x15 grid, then store the coordinates of those centers into a separate array. I hope this makes sense, but I am happy to answer any questions to specify what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went another route, convoluting the image by summing the pixel values and re-normalising until the picture doesn't change. My bold hypothesis is that you're left with the candidates for centre points:

```
from numpy import array, max, where

img = """00011111100000000111111000
00111111110000001111111100
01111111111000011111111110
01111111111000011111111110
01111111111000011111111110
01111111111000011111111110
01111111111000011111111110
01111111111000011111111110
00111111110000001111111100
00011111100000000111111000"""

img = array([[int(i) for i in row] for row in img.split("\n")], int)

print(img)
print()

def convolute(img):
    s_x, s_y = img.shape
    result = array(img)
    for dx in (-1, 0, 1):
        for dy in (-1, 0, 1):
            result[1:s_x - 2, 1:s_y - 2] += img[1 + dx: s_x - 2 + dx,
                                                1 + dy: s_y - 2 + dy]

    # focus on the centers
    result[result<max(result)] = 0
    result[result > 0] = 1
    return result
    
while True:
    img2 = convolute(img)
    if (img2 == img).all():
        break
    img = img2
    print(img)
    print()
    
indices = where(img)
for x, y in zip(indices[0], indices[1]):
    print(x, y)
```

In this case, you'll end up with a list of coordinates:

```
4 5
4 6
4 19
4 20
5 5
5 6
5 19
5 20
```

The first four are for the left dot, the second four for the right dot.

**Edit**: Assuming there are only spots of maximal 2x2 left, this should work now:

```
# now filter out all but bottom right corners
img[:-1,:-1] &= 1 - (img[1:,:-1] | img[:-1, 1:])
```

A pixel only survives if not the bottom or right neighbour is on.

Comment: So I think you are on to something here. Now I wanna specify that I actually have an array that is 1260x683 elements the figures where just for demonstration purposes. How would I fix your code to get  img defined from an Numpy array?

Comment: Haha, did you realise, I first converted your string into a numpy array? ;-)

Comment: Ok, so I first wanted to say thank for the great help :D I was able  to adapt this to my project and was able to get all the results stored into a text doc. Now I see that this identifies four center pixels. Is there a way to make it only store the bottom right of those 4?

Comment: I edited the post ... this should do the job, but I didn't think a lot about it, and maybe there are cases in which it fails.

Comment: So I talked with my friend and we seem to have a pretty sure fire idea of how to make sure we get the correct ones every time. The bottom right pixel will always fall on an odd x value and an odd y value. We considered using the modulus tool to do this. I can try to see how your edit will work but I am unsure as to where in the above code to implement it.